# How to mock a spring injected service proxy?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jmockit

I am trying to unit test a Spring MVC based Controller.
This controller calls out to a service. That service is actually remote, and is exposed to the controller via JSON-RPC, and specifically, a com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonProxyFactoryBean

The Controller has:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    /**
     * ID manager service that will be used.
     */
    @Autowired
    IdMService idMService;
    ...
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = GET)
    public UserAccountDTO getUser(@PathVariable Long userId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        try {
            return idMService.getUser(userId);
        } catch (JsonRpcClientException se) {
            sendJsonEncodedErrorRepsonse(response, se);
            return null;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The spring configuration provides the IdMService like this:

```
<!-- Create the proxy for the Access Control service -->
<bean class="com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.spring.JsonProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="${access_control.service.url}" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.phtcorp.service.accesscontrol.IdMService" />
</bean>
```

Thus, the IdMService that gets injected into the controller is actually a JSON-RPC proxy, implementing the IdMService interface.

I would like to test the controller, but mock the IdMService. I have this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test-context.xml" })
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class TestUserController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;

    @Mocked IdMService service;

    @Test
    public void getUser() throws Exception {
        request.setMethod(RequestMethod.GET.name());
        request.setRequestURI("/users/1");
        HandlerMethod handler = (HandlerMethod) getHandler(request);
        handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);
        new Verifications() {{
            service.getUser(1L); times=1;
        }};
    }
...
}
```

However, I find that IdMService that is injected into the controller is not a mock, it is a JsonRpcProxy after all.  I have successfully tested a different controller in this manner, but that one does not use a proxy to its service.

So the question is: how do I use jmockit to cause a mock IdMService to be injected into the UserController?  Note that I'm not instantiating the UserController myself, anywhere; spring/spring-mvc does that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are unit testing your UserController, why not just instantiate it yourself. Get Spring out of the picture and just test it all on its own.

You are not testing the UserController here so much as testing the Spring wiring of it and the  request mapping for it.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that I'm not instantiating the UserController myself, anywhere; spring/spring-mvc does that.

This means that you're not writing a unit test. This is testing the spring wiring which makes it an integration test. When writing a unit test you instantiate the class under test and supply the dependencies yourself. This allows you to isolate the logic in the class being tested by providing mocked instances of the classes dependencies. That's where jmockit comes in.

Comment: Indeed, the best thing here is to instantiate `UserController` in the test. Then it should work. Alternatively, using `@Capturing` in addition to `@Mocked` in the mock field should also work, since JMockit would then mock all implementing classes for the duration of the test.

Comment: Yep. I didn't really want to focus on the specific mocking framework since that's just an after-thought. The important thing to grasp here is the difference between unit testing and integration testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Interesting; it may or may not be unit testing, but it is what I want to test. The controller is for a REST API. It does almost nothing; it calls down into service methods almost immediately.  What I'm concerned with is its behavior as a controller; whether my URL's end up calling the right service methods with the right parameters.  To me, the Java method signature of the controller methods is insignificant. The API is the URL space.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by injecting the mock myself:

```
@Mocked IdMService service;

@Before
public void setUp() {
 controller.setIdMService(service);
   ...
}
```